# Pigeonhole Principle Question: Given any 5 points inside a square of side length 2, there is always a pair whose distance apart is at most $\sqrt2$

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

The question I am looking at:

Prove that given 5 points inside a square of side length 2, it is always possible to find two of them whose distance apart is at most $\sqrt2$.

This looks to me like I should try to apply the Pigeonhole Principle, though I can't see a way to do it. If anyone can send me in the right direction?...

Comment: Divide the square into 4 smaller squares.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/101692/3111): The answer is given away in the statement of this earlier Question.

Comment: Okay so we split the 2x2 square into $4$ $1$x$1$ squares, and then we place the points into the $4$ $1$x$1$ squares. By the pigeonhole-principle, some $1$x$1$ square will have to contain at least $2$ points. And the largest distance that the $2$ points in this square can be is the length of the diagonal - $\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt{2}$. Thanks for giving just the right amount of hint.

Comment: Nice suggestion by Gerry. My first thought was divide the square into four isoceles triangles with bases on the sides and the other sides along the diagonals.

Comment: @Maylor:  Why not take the opportunity to Answer this Question yourself, now that you've gotten "just the right amount of hint" from Gerry?  That way others can benefit from your write-up, and the Question will not show up on lists of unanswered posts.

Comment: I have posted my answer now, though I am a fairly new user and apparently I cannot accept the answer for two more days. I will make sure I do that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Credit to @Gerry_Myerson for inspiration.

We have a 2x2 square. We want to split this into 4 1x1 squares, simply by joining the centres of opposite sides. This creates a small grid.

Now imagine we want to insert our 5 points into these 4 1x1 squares. Here we apply the pigeonhole principle. Since we have more points than squares to place them, we know that some square must end up containing at least 2 points.

So now we know that given any 5 points inside a square of side length 2, we can find two of them that lie in some square of side length 1. What is the maximum distance apart that these can be? It's obvious (and prove-able, though I won't do it here) that the two points are maximum distance apart when they lie on opposite corners. By simple Pythagoras', we know that the length of the diagonal of a square of side length 1 is $\sqrt2$, so we have the required result.