# How to prove that the max distance between 5 points on a unit square perimeter is 0.75

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

5 Ants are walking across a squared window, with the side length of 1 meter.
I need to prove that in any given moment there are at least two ants the the distance between them is less than 75 cm. 
I simplified the problem to the title: "How to prove that the max distance between 5 points on a unit square perimeter is 0.75", But I need to prove it without using calculus, I need to use Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: See this very similar problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741941/pigeonhole-principle-question-given-any-5-points-inside-a-square-of-side-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the unit square into $4$ small squares of side $0.5$.

According to the Pigeonhole principle, there are at least 2 points in the same small square.

The maximum distance between two points in the small square is the distance of the diagonal, that is equal to $\sqrt{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \approx 0.71$ (cm)  $< 0.75$ (cm)

Comment: The question asker said it was their job to prove it. You have not given them any room to do that.